# Adding element to element to array using [this.length]

Tags: javascript, arrays, this

I am trying to add items to an array by using the current array length as the next index. For example:

```
var arr = ["one","two","three"];
arr[this.length] = "four";
```

but it just replaces the first element with the new element so i get `["four", "two", "three"]`. Is `this` not referring to the array?

Comment: `arr[arr.length] = "four"`. Or you can just [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the new item: `arr.push("four")` and it will be inserted automatically after the last item of `arr`.

Comment: Can you post the full code?

Answer (score 5):

You're actually using the property `length` from `Window` object.

> #### [Window.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/length)
>
> Returns the number of frames (either  or  elements) in the window.

*In your case, is returning `0`.*

```js
console.log("length" in window);
console.log(window.length);
```

What you actually want to do is

```js
var arr = ["one","two","three"];
arr[arr.length] = "four";

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is `this` not referring to the array?

No, it does not. To understand the meaning of `this`, read https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp. In your code here, you need to use `arr.length` instead. Alternatively, you can use `arr.push()` to append an element to the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

with ES6 destructor syntax without side effects...

```
const arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
const withFour = [...arr, 'four'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use the `Array.prototype.push` method?

```
var arr = ["one","two","three"];
arr.push("four");
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push